# enviar datos desde una vista a un controlador de Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

Agradeceré su ayuda con lo siguiente, no estoy seguro si lo estoy haciendo bien y la documentación no logro entenderla.

Tengo un archivo blade que llama a una vista livewire del siguiente modo:

```
@livewire('single-chart',['tabla_grupo' => $tabla_grupo,'nombre_grupo' => $nombre_grupo])
```

Como verán al controlador "SingleChart", trato de enviarle los valores de las variables php $tabla_grupo y $nombre_grupo, pero no logro recibirlas en el controlador de livewire para luego enviarlos a la vista

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class SingleChart extends Component
{
    public $tabla_grupo, $titulo_grupo; 
    
    
    public function render()
    {
     
     //Más código que usa las variables $tabla_grupo y $titulo_grupo
     
     return view('livewire.single-chart',["tabla_grupo" => $tabla_grupo, "titulo_grupo" => $titulo_grupo]);
    }

}
```

He intentado de varias formas según la documentación y no logro obtener resultados. ¿Me podrían indicar como debe ser por favor?

muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

luego de ver y ver tutoriales y de leer y leer la documentación e logrado dar con mi error.

Resulta que debía pasar las variables del siguiente modo dentro de public function render():

```
$this->tabla_grupo = $tabla_grupo;
$this->nombre_grupo = $nombre_grupo;
```

Con eso logré mi objetivo, ahora a seguir aprendiendo.

Espero que sea de utilidad para alguien